# charles proxy not working on private network 192.168.X.X

Tags: android, proxy, charles-proxy

I am trying to intercept server requests from a mobile app using charles proxy. I have used charles proxy intensively , But for some reason I am not able to record the sessions on a local wifi. One thing which I noticed is selecting Help--> Local Ip address from the menu doesn't show up the local IP address. I am not able to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the IP address of your computer that is running Charles into the Android device's Wifi Settings. Also ensure that both the device and your computer are on the same subnet.